# Understanding a case of multi-variate chain rule for matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I am trying to understand an example for computing derivatives using matrix calculus in the context of the back-propagation algorithm used in deep learning. If I have a real-valued $K \times K$ matrix $A$, and a vector $x$ of dimension $K$, then let
$w = Ax$ and $L = ||w||^2$, and consider $L$ a function of $A$ and $x$.

Then the multi-variate chain rule says that $$\frac{ \partial L }{\partial A} = \frac{ \partial L }{\partial w} \frac { \partial w }{\partial A}$$

Now I am trying to figure out what the shape of the matrices in this equation should be. I know $$\frac{\partial L} {\partial w} = [2 w_1, \ldots, 2 w_K]$$ i.e a tensor of shape $(1, K)$.

Then the shape of $\frac{\partial w} {\partial A}$ is confusing me. Since $w$ is a $K$ dimensional vector and $A$ is of size $K \times K$, it seems that if you flatten $A$ to a vector (in either row major or column major order), and index its entries from $A_i$  as $1 \leq i \leq K^2$, you could treat $\frac{\partial w} {\partial A}$ as a matrix of size $K \times K^2 $, but I feel this is not the convention. What is the shape of $\frac{\partial w} {\partial A}$ ?

Also $L$ is a scalar-valued function, so I think $\frac{\partial L} {\partial A}$ should be a vector of size $K^2$, or a matrix of size $K \times K$, but I am not sure about this either. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace/Frobenius product is
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \;=\; {\rm Tr}(A^TA) \\
}$$
Write the cost function using this notation. Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
L &= \|w\|^2 = w:w \\
dL &= 2w:dw \;=\; 2w:(dA\,x) \;=\; 2wx^T:dA \\
\frac{ \partial L }{\partial A} &= 2wx^T \;=\; 2Axx^T \\
}$$
The differential approach obviates the need to calculate higher-order tensors, such as matrix-by-vector, vector-by-matrix, or matrix-by-matrix gradients.

It also avoids common pitfalls involving transposed matrices or vectors.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with the notion of the differential of a matrix/vector, otherwise thanks I will study this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume, for simplicity, $K=2$, then

$$
\partial_A L = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{a_{11}} L && \partial_{a_{12}} L \\
\partial_{a_{21}} L && \partial_{a_{22}} L
\end{array}
\right).
$$

If $L$ is a function of the vector ${w}(a_{ij})$, then

$$
\partial_{a_{ij}} L({w}(a_{ij})) = \partial_{w_1}L \; \partial_{a_{ij}} w_1 + \partial_{w_2}L \; \partial_{a_{ij}} w_2.
$$

Given in matrix notation

$$
\partial_A L =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\partial_{w_1} L \; I_{2 \times 2} && \partial_{w_2} L \; I_{2 \times 2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\partial_A w_1 \\
\partial_A w_2
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Hence, the general shape of $\partial_Aw$ is $K^2 \times K$.

Comment: This is basically what I thought, but are you sure the shape isn't $K^2 \times K$?

Comment: $\partial_A w_i \in \mathbb{C}^{K \times K}, \; i = 1...K$ stacked in a column has size $K^2 \times K$, yes.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with your notation. What is $\partial_A{L}$ ?

Comment: Apologies, $\partial_A L := \frac{\partial L}{\partial A}$.